Where did the statement "The Catholic Church prohibited the commonwealth from reading the Bible" come from?
The Douay-Rheims Bible has a letter from Pope Pius VI saying that "these are the most abundant sources which ought to be left open to every one." Many bishops too ask Christians to read the Bible for themselves. I am not Christian myself but am interested in medieval Europe, so I would appreciate it if you could guide me in tracking down the origin of this fallacy.

Where did you come across this statement?

Maybe you are referring to the fact that it was not permitted to translate the Bible into the vernacular. In principle there was no rule against ordinary people reading the Bible in Latin, but since most couldn't it amounted to the same thing.

Presumably you mean 'the common people' rather than 'the commonwealth'?

@xcda64,  After Martin Luther began the Protestant Reformation(1517) he emphasized sola scriptura ("Scripture alone") should lead the faithful.  Then he set about translating and printing bibles.  The Catholic Church responded with The Council of Trent (1545–1563) affirming the importance of the Vulgate and established controls on vernacular translations to ensure doctrinal accuracy.  This lead the Catholic Church burning protestant translated bibles as heretical.  And a few Protestants who translated them.

John Wycliffe (1328–1384): English theologian, After his death, the Church condemned him as a heretic, and his remains were exhumed and burned. William Tyndale (1494–1536): Translated bible, condemned as heretic, was strangled and burned at the stake in 1536 Jan Hus (1372–1415): He was burned at the stake for heresy in 1415.

There were bibles in other languages, including english, in the middle ages.
Here you can find a list [1]:
Plus a famous one in spanish [2]
And a 3-language latin-greek-hebrew from 1502 [3].
But they were rare, because their cost/benefit ratio was bad.
Translating the whole bible is hard work, even today. If it is not done carefully, people will complain about inaccuracies, or even accuse the writers (or the approving bishop) of incompetence or even heresy. Plus,  "printing" (i.e. copying by hand) the whole bible would be expensive. In practice, no commoner would have a bible at home. And the rich learned Latin, off course.
And all that work for what?
For much of the middle ages, most literate people were taught to read Latin before their vernacular language, or even only Latin (see [i]). And as more people learned to read than to write, even copying by hand small passages for personal devotion in the vernacular would be useful for a very small set of people.
Another reason: the vernacular language were not fully developed. They lacked standardization, sometimes even dictionaries, and were too regional - something written in one region would not be understood well in another region. Usually one wants the bible to be well understood, including technical philosophical, historical, theological terms. It is still hard today to translate the bible into languages without a well developed literature.
So, a vernacular bible would be useful: only to the very few people literate in the vernacular but not in Latin; and only in a small region. For the dialect beyond the next river, inconsistencies and inaccuracies would become evident.
Besides, some languages evolved quite fast before great books appeared to standardize them (e.g. Dante, Chaucer, Shakespeare, Cervantes, Camões), and the standardization process was often slow (no TV back then). A bible written in the language of Beowulf would be useful for how long? If you were a monk writing 100 years  after Beowulf, would you judge more useful to copy a bible in Latin, or in Beowulf-english (consider how much time you would spend..)?
Why would a bishop authorize (and probably finance) such a expensive work for so little gain? Yet they did it, sometimes, but rarely.
As you can see in the reference [1], once vernacular languages became more standardized and more widely taught, more vernacular catholic bibles  appeared, even more so when the printing press was invented, and well before the protestants.
Moreover, once states started to centralize in the modern period, having a bible written in the court language would be a nice easy way to push the standardization of the vernacular towards the court version (if the king speaks like that, it must be the right way...). This may explain the push for vernacular bibles which were not needed in the decentralized middle ages.
From [1] "if we may believe the testimony of Archbishop Cranmer, Sir Thomas More, Foxe the martyrologist, and the authors of the Preface to the Reims Testament, the whole Bible was to be found in the mother tongue long before John Wyclif was born (cf. "American Ecclesiastical Review", XXXII, Philadelphia, June, 1905, 594)."
[i] The Envy of Angels, Stephen Jaeger, 1994
[1]: https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/15367a.htm
[2]: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblia_alfonsina
[3]: https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05286a.htm
